# How to deal with non-comparable elements in the partial order set in the formal proof

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

If $X$ is any partially ordered set and $f,g\in i\mathbb{R}^X$, then

$\alpha f+\beta g\in i\mathbb{R}^X$ whenever $\alpha,\beta\geqslant 0$

---

$i\mathbb{R}^X$ is the set of increasing functions, and increasing function $f\in\mathbb{R}^X$ is defined as $x,x'\in X$, $x\preceq x'\implies f(x)\leq f(x')$

---

**This is a somewhat trivial question; below is my attempt.**

**However, there is a flaw in my argument about how I should reason the non-comparable elements in the poset, not every pair of elements needs to be comparable in the poset. My proof already presumes every element is comparable so as can be indexed by $n,n-1$**

Given $f,g\in i\mathbb{R}^X$, then $f_{n-1}\leqslant f_n$ and $g_{n-1}\leqslant g_n$ for all $n\in X$, then any $\alpha,\beta\geqslant 0$ maintains $\alpha f_{n-1}\leqslant\alpha f_n$ and $\beta g_{n-1}\leqslant\beta g_n$. Then $$\alpha f_{n-1}+\beta g_{n-1}\leqslant\alpha f_n+\beta g_n$$ for all $n\in X$. Hence, $\alpha f+\beta g\in i\mathbb{R}^X$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: could you please define the notation you use, what is $i\mathbb{R}^X$? presumably some poset with an underlying set of functions, but a precise definition is needed

Comment: @Carlyle my bad, the question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would argue directly from definition of $i\mathbb{R}^X$ and work with arbitrary elements $x, x' \in X$ with $x \preceq x'$, instead of trying to place a total order on $X$. Here's a very slight modification of your proof which works:

Let $f,g \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing functions with respect to the partial order on $X$ and the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$. Suppose $x,x'\in X$ are such that $x \preceq x'$. Then $f(x) \leq f(x')$ and $g(x) \leq g(x')$ since $f$ and $g$ are increasing. Also, since $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$, we have $\alpha f(x) \leq \alpha f(x')$ and $\beta g(x) \leq \beta g(x')$. Adding the inequalities to each other, we obtain
$$\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) \leq \alpha f(x') + \beta g(x').$$
So $\alpha f + \beta g$ is also an increasing function.